# How to split Strings into all possible n-grams / all possible 6-grams

Tags: java, string, substring, talend, n-gram

Ok, here is my input

**ProductName**

Machinery

Machinery, big

Farming Machinery

Applejuice

Juice Machines

Software Development

Business Development

Software Licensing

Eggs

...

Productname can be any String with varying lengths - Min(Length()) actually is 3, but assume Max(Length()) can be anything from 15 to 50(?).

What i need is

a) Extract every possible 6-gram from the Source List above (Save it somewhere?)
b) See how often each of these 6-grams can be found in the Source List

a)
"Machin"
"achine"
"chiner"
"hinery"
"inery,"
"nery, "
"ery, B"
"ry, Bi"
...
"icensi"
"censin"
"ensing"
"Eggs"

b)
Basically, SELECT <6-gram> AS gram, COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE productname like '%<6-gram>%'
(Or maybe with a JOIN, if grams are stored in a different table)

I can do it using a TJava Component and a GlobalVar Set Object (kinda as seen here: http://bekwam.blogspot.de/2012/08/iterating-over-java-collection-with.html), putting one String at a time into the TJava Component and making a Set of all possible 6-grams, which can be processed afterwards. (Set, because i dont need duplicates)

Is there an easier, better way to do this? Preferably without TJava Component? I use Talend Open Studio for Data Integration 99% of the time, maybe other components can do this?
If there is no better way to do this, how can i re-use the code in other Jobs & Projects / make it more dynamic by allowing to chose 4-gram, 5-gram, n-gram.

First Question put up here, so forgive me if its not specific enough / bad English / not precise enough. Criticism welcome

SELECT Greetings FROM Germany
Stefan

Comment: Do you mean a rolling-window of 6-grams? Just confirming, since that's what it looks like based on your example.

Comment: Which java version are you using? Java-8 or lower?

Answer (score 0):

There is no component that make this, to make your code reusable, just use a [user routine](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Creating+a+user+routine+and+call+it+in+a+Job), its visible from any job in the project. Alternative way is to pack it in a jar file and load it when you need using [tLibraryLoad](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tLibraryLoad).
To make your code dynamic you can use [context variables](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendPlatformforEnterpriseIntegrationwithBigDataStudioUserGuide56EN/4.6.1+How+to+define+context+variables+for+a+Job) and pass it to your method like this : `MyStaticRoutine.getNgrams(input,n);`